# Вопрос касательно методов Ruby

Tags: ruby

В чем разница между методами `map` и `collect`?

Подскажите плиз когда использовать `map`, а когда `collect`?

Comment: Идеология руби в том, чтобы человеко-читабельно выражать мысль. Поэтому многие методы имеют синонимы (что не все любят) и множество методов выражающих мысль словами. Например k==0 заменяется на k.zero? 
Так что использовать лучше то, что принято использовать в команде или сильнее выражает суть.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Абсолютно никакой разницы.

Исходники этих методов указывают в один и тот же код на Си.
(для массивов они реализованы на Си отдельно, но тоже одинаково)

- Проверьте сами, установив и запустив `pry` и сделав на интересующем объекте `obj`:

  ```
  show-source obj.collect
  show-source obj.map
  ```

---

Что использовать — **холивар**.

- Есть лица, считающие, что надо использовать их так, чтобы код хорошо читался. В этом контексте обычно лучше работает `collect` (собрать), как "собрать результаты выполнения блока для каждого элемента".
- Есть лица, считающие, что надо всегда использовать `map`, потому что это широко известная (вне Ruby) операция преобразования данных, в которой каждый элемент коллекции преобразуется независимо от остальных.
- [Есть лица](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wTEQ0VN8iM), жалеющие, что в Ruby так много синонимов и потому так много споров о чисто косметических вещах (bikeshedding).

  - `collect_concat` vs. `flat_map`
  - `reduce` vs. `inject`
  - `detect` vs. `find`
  - `find_all` vs. `select`
  - `include?` vs. `member?`

Comment: Спасибо **D-side** теперь мне стало понятно!!!